# jquery swap slider not working width link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one question about my swap slider. I have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/03868dc2119653bb05f76523a2f1a73d)** from codepen.

Problems link in the left part of the demo big images does not change automatically. So if i change :

***this***

```
<li class="active"><a href=""><img src="sss.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
<li><a href=""><img src="fff.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
```

***to this:***

```
<li class="active"><img src="abc.jpg" alt="" /></li>
<li><img src="ddd.jpg" alt="" /></li>
```

then image changed automatically. What i need to do change link with the pictures?

I am using this jquery function:

```
var autoScrollerTimer = null;
var autoScrollerTimerTwo = null;
function autoChangeImage() {
    autoScrollerTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        $("#magazin_sldwr li.active")
            .removeClass('active')
            .nextThumb()
            .addClass('active')
            .children('img')
            .trigger('mouseenter');
        autoChangeImage();
    }, 2000);
}
function autoChangeImageTwo() {
    autoScrollerTimerTwo = setTimeout(function(){
        $("#magazin_sldwr2 li.active")
            .removeClass('active')
            .nextThumb()
            .addClass('active')
            .children('img')
            .trigger('mouseenter');
        autoChangeImageTwo();
    }, 3000);
}
$(document).ready(function() {

    var c;
    $("#magazin_sldwr li img").hover(function(){
        c = $(this).attr('alt');
        clearTimeout(autoScrollerTimer);

$(".title").remove(); $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        $('#mainm-img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/', '')).parent().attr('href',$(this).parent().attr('href'),$("#mainm-img").parent().append('<div class="title">' + c + '</div>'));

    }, function(){
        autoChangeImage();
    });
    var imgSwap = [];
     $("#magazin_sldwr li img").each(function(){
        imgUrl = this.src.replace('thumb/', '');
        imgSwap.push(imgUrl);
    });


    autoChangeImage();

    $("#magazin_sldwr2 li img").hover(function(){
        clearTimeout(autoScrollerTimerTwo);
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        $('#mainm-img2').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/', ''));
    }, function(){
        autoChangeImageTwo();
    });
    var imgSwap = [];
     $("#magazin_sldwr2 li img").each(function(){
        imgUrl = this.src.replace('thumb/', '');
        imgSwap.push(imgUrl);
    });


    autoChangeImageTwo();

});
$.fn.nextThumb = function(){
    var next = $(this).next('li');
    if (next.length) {
        return next;
    } else {
        return $(this).parent().find('li:first');
    }
};
$.fn.preload = function() {
    this.each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var autoScrollerTimer = null;
var autoScrollerTimerTwo = null;
function autoChangeImage() {
    autoScrollerTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        $("#magazin_sldwr li.active")
            .removeClass('active')
            .nextThumb()
            .addClass('active')
            .find('img')
            .trigger('mouseenter');
        autoChangeImage();
    }, 2000);
}
function autoChangeImageTwo() {
    autoScrollerTimerTwo = setTimeout(function(){
        $("#magazin_sldwr2 li.active")
            .removeClass('active')
            .nextThumb()
            .addClass('active')
            .children('img')
            .trigger('mouseenter');
        autoChangeImageTwo();
    }, 3000);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  
 var c;
 $("#magazin_sldwr li img").hover(function(){
        c = $(this).attr('alt');
        clearTimeout(autoScrollerTimer);
       
$(".title").remove(); $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  $('#mainm-img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/', '')).parent().attr('href',$(this).parent().attr('href'),$("#mainm-img").parent().append('<div class="title">' + c + '</div>'));
        
    }, function(){
        autoChangeImage();
    });
 var imgSwap = [];
  $("#magazin_sldwr li img").each(function(){
  imgUrl = this.src.replace('thumb/', '');
  imgSwap.push(imgUrl);
 });
  
 
    autoChangeImage();
  
   $("#magazin_sldwr2 li img").hover(function(){
        clearTimeout(autoScrollerTimerTwo);
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  $('#mainm-img2').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/', ''));
    }, function(){
        autoChangeImageTwo();
    });
 var imgSwap = [];
  $("#magazin_sldwr2 li img").each(function(){
  imgUrl = this.src.replace('thumb/', '');
  imgSwap.push(imgUrl);
 });
  
 
    autoChangeImageTwo();
  
});
$.fn.nextThumb = function(){
    var next = $(this).next('li');
    if (next.length) {
        return next;
    } else {
        return $(this).parent().find('li:first');
    }
};
$.fn.preload = function() {
    this.each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
};
```

```css
body,html,div,blockquote,img,label,p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,ul,ol,li,dl,dt,dd,form,a,fieldset,input,th,td{border:0;outline:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
body{height:100%;background:#fff;color:#1f1f1f;font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode","Lucida Grande",Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;font-size:13px;padding:7px 0;}

#magazin_sldwr {width: 400px; margin: 0 auto; float:left;}
#magazin_sldwr ul {padding-left: 10px; ist-style:none; float:left;}
#magazin_sldwr li {display: inline; margin-right: 1px; float:left;}
#magazin_sldwr #mainm-img {background: url(bg_img.png) no-repeat 0 0; padding: 6px; width:400px; height:240px; }
#magazin_sldwr li img {
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  float:left;
}
#magazin_sldwr ul li:hover img{
 border:1px solid blue;
 }

#magazin_sldwr2 {width: 400px; margin: 0 auto; float:left;}
#magazin_sldwr2 ul {padding-left: 10px; ist-style:none; float:left;}
#magazin_sldwr2 li {display: inline; margin-right: 1px; float:left;}
#magazin_sldwr2 #mainm-img2 {background: url(bg_img.png) no-repeat 0 0; padding: 6px; width:400px; height:240px; }
#magazin_sldwr2 li img {
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  float:left;
}
#magazin_sldwr2 ul li:hover img{
 border:1px solid blue;
}
.title {
    position:absolute;top:20px;left:20px;background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
 <div id="magazin_sldwr">
    <a href=""><img src="http://p1.pichost.me/640/14/1372030.jpg" alt="" id="mainm-img" /></a>
 <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href=""><img src="http://p1.pichost.me/640/14/1372030.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
   <li><a href=""><img src="http://p1.pichost.me/640/20/1426650.jpg" alt="fdsafadsff" /></a></li>
   <li><a href=""><img src="http://p1.pichost.me/640/16/1386887.jpg" alt="fdassfasf" /></a></li>
   <li><a href=""><img src="http://p1.pichost.me/640/14/1371215.jpg" alt="fdsaeefasf" /></a></li>
   <li><a href=""><img src="http://p1.pichost.me/640/14/1372030.jpg" alt="fds22333afasf" /></a></li>
   <li><a href=""><img src="http://p1.pichost.me/640/14/1372034.jpg" alt="fds5566afasf" /></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
    
    <div class="wrap">
 <div id="magazin_sldwr2">
 <img src="http://p1.pichost.me/640/14/1372030.jpg" alt="" id="mainm-img2" />
 <ul>
   <li class="active"><img src="http://p1.pichost.me/640/14/1372030.jpg" alt="" /></li>
   <li><img src="http://p1.pichost.me/640/20/1426650.jpg" alt="fdsdf" /></li>
   <li><img src="http://p1.pichost.me/640/16/1386887.jpg" alt="" /></li>
   <li><img src="http://p1.pichost.me/640/14/1371215.jpg" alt="" /></li>
   <li><img src="http://p1.pichost.me/640/14/1372030.jpg" alt="" /></li>
   <li><img src="http://p1.pichost.me/640/14/1372034.jpg" alt="" /></li>
 </ul>
</div
  </div>
```

change
`$("#magazin_sldwr li.active")
            .removeClass('active')
            .nextThumb()
            .addClass('active')
            .children('img')
            .trigger('mouseenter');`
to
`$("#magazin_sldwr li.active")
            .removeClass('active')
            .nextThumb()
            .addClass('active')
            .find('img')
            .trigger('mouseenter');`
or
`$("#magazin_sldwr li.active")
            .removeClass('active')
            .nextThumb()
            .addClass('active')
            .children('a')
            .children('img')
            .trigger('mouseenter');`

find() searches through the children and gets all the elements that match. children goes down a single dom level at a time so needs to be a the img

see:
http://api.jquery.com/find/
http://api.jquery.com/children/

Answer (score 0):

Look at your construct: children only travels a single level down the DOM tree, so it wont find a img-tag beacause there is an a tag before. Try selecting the img through "a>img"

http://api.jquery.com/children/

So your choice should either be to use children twice or find("a>img")